# Weird redirect after login with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have this application where I use Devise and, after login the user is redirected to a blank page with the path `/users/sign_in.user`.

Why is Devise redirecting to this path? Here's the log entry I get:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in.user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-10 15:56:03 -0200
  Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as 
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ukqyLFgApCSybuIlVynPwj/xgdI/WuHLxoFxOsY4wgQ=", "user"=>{"email"=>"felipe.coury@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Entrar"}
  User Load (1.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'felipe.coury@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (1.0ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_sign_in_at` = '2011-11-09 18:47:04', `current_sign_in_at` = '2011-11-10 17:56:04', `sign_in_count` = 14, `updated_at` = '2011-11-10 17:56:04' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 112ms
```

Here's my complete `routes.rb` file:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "site#home"
  match 'biblioteca' => 'site#library', :as => :library

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" }
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  resources :cursos
  resources :matriculas
  resources :modulo_statuses
end
```

I tried using `after_sign_in_path_for` in `ApplicationController`:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  Rails.logger.info "***** LOGGED IN, GOING TO #{root_path}"
  root_path
end
```

But the log entry doesn't even appear.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably happening because something like this is being called: `user_session_path(user)` and you actually don't need the user as argument, so Rails treats it as the format. This is likely wrong in the `form_for` call in your sign in view. `after_sign_in_path_for` is not being called because Rails is not considering the given URL a valid request (that's why the response is 406 acceptable).

Comment: Nada como falar direto com a fonte, né? Thanks José!