# Redirect of registrations using Devise fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

We set up Devise for our Rails application and everything works wonderfully. That is everything except redirect after registration. Every time a new user is created he's taken to http://localhost:3000/register.user

A lot of others seems to have had problems with sign up - and then solved their problems. These two guides seemed to be particularly relevant:

[Devise redirect after sign up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987841/devise-redirect-after-sign-up)

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)

Currently we're running a setup like the one recommended in the How To from the Devise developer mentioned above.

If I look at the output from the server it says:

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as 
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"ANhNV4Q/XRsSdnAGoxIeB2PWOXsp+2afDe2r/0M7ISY=", "user"=>{"email"=>"new@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "full_name"=>"", "company"=>""}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
(0.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 
---- THIS PART ASSUMED TO BE OKAY ----- 
(0.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = '2011-11-12 18:41:02.094825', "current_sign_in_at" = '2011-11-12 18:41:02.094825', "last_sign_in_ip" = '127.0.0.1', "current_sign_in_ip" = '127.0.0.1', "sign_in_count" = 1, "updated_at" = '2011-11-12 18:41:02.095195' WHERE "users"."id" = 32
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 282ms
```

It's the last line that makes me think the problem has little to do with the answers to the other questions asked and answered.

I hope someone can help. I can put up routes.rb etc. if needed, I just don't know how much to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is pretty similar to this: [Weird redirect after login with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084335/weird-redirect-after-login-with-devise).

Try to see if you're calling any `user_session_path(user)` or `user_registration_path(user)` (maybe you're doing this on your `form_for`). Since `user_session_path` doesn't require any arguments, Rails treats it as a format and returns `406`.

EDIT: Added "or `user_registration_path(user)` (maybe you're doing this on your `form_for`)"

Comment: Thanks, Rodrigo. I searched the project for the two paths without finding anything. The form looks like this:


= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|

Comment: It worked. Just had to remove "resource_name" from the path. Thanks!

Comment: @jakobkpoulsen could you be more explicit regarding what you did to solve your problem.  I'm having it too!  Thanks in advance.