# Strange behavior when using devise: do not redirect to root_path after sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Rails 3.2.2 and Devise 2.0.4

the devise doc says after signing up, it will redirect to root_path

I have set the root_path:

```
root :to => 'dreams#index'
```

however, after signing up, the URL changed to

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_in.user
```

It happens not just after signing up, the same thing occurs after change password and so on..

each time. only a ".user" is appended to the url..nothing else happens

where is the problem?

Comment: what do you have in your config/routes.rb file?

Comment: Check the form_for call on your sign_up form:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084335/weird-redirect-after-login-with-devise

Answer (score 3):

In your sign in form you need replace little bit!

You have:

```
form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_path(resource_name))
```

You need:

```
form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_path)
```

With simple_form it works too.

Comment: Thank the lord for this answer!!! I couldn't figure out why I was having this problem and searched forever.